# how can I fix "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration"

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to run the following code:

```
def load_scan(path):
    slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.InstanceNumber))
    try:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImagePositionPatient[2] - slices[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
    except StopIteration:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)

    for s in slices:
        s.SliceThickness = slice_thickness

    return slices

id=0
patient = load_scan(data_path)
```

but I'm getting error:

> RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration

I use python 3.7

Comment: Try formatting your question so the code and question are both easy to identify and understand.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of a perhaps incompatible version of (py)dicom with python3, in the kaggle kernel, fix is simple:
just switch from *dicom*, to `pydicom` e.g

```
def load_scan(path):
    slices = [pydicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: float(x.ImagePositionPatient[2]))
    try:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImagePositionPatient[2] - slices[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
    except:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)
    for s in slices:
        s.SliceThickness = slice_thickness        
    return slices
```

and the following code will work:

```
train_patient_ids = os.listdir(os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'train'))
test_patient_ids = os.listdir(os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'test'))
first_patient = load_scan(os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'train',train_patient_ids[0]))
first_patient_pixels = get_pixels_hu(first_patient)
plt.hist(first_patient_pixels.flatten(), bins=80, color='c')
plt.xlabel("Hounsfield Units (HU)")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()

plt.imshow(first_patient_pixels[80], cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```